# Registry seems locked for a user at Windows Creators update

Tags: windows, javafx, windows-creators

I have a **bundled 32-bit** JavaFX Desktop Application, that worked on many machines (Mac and Windows OS) successfully for several years, until Windows Creators update was released.
Since that update we observed several computers where application can't start (It launches an Alert Dialog saying : Error Invoking Method -> Can't start JVM).
The exception was `JavaSecurityException` cannot read from HKLM\JavaSoft\Prefs\Some_PATH.

Calling preferences as follows:

```
Preferences.systemNodeForPackage(MyPreferences.class).node(myNode);
```

The most strange thing in all this, that on some machines "Run as Administrator" helped and on others did not. But "Run in compatibility mode Windows 8" worked on all machines. Also on some machines it works for one user (sometimes administrator, sometimes not) and doesn't work for all the other users.
We need using HKLM since we have feature that only admin should write and users can read.
Did anyone else faced this issue? Investigating the internet didn't help. Please, advice.

Comment: This feels like more of a Windows issue/question... Not sure how you can circumvent it in Java. Have you tried asking on Microsoft's help forums?

Comment: it seems so, I've wrote a bat script to read the registry and it fails also. I can't find appropriate Thread on MS forums.

Comment: Process Monitor would probably be the best diagnostic tool to begin with.  See what's actually happening, from the kernel's point of view, in both the situations where it works and the situations where it doesn't.

Comment: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-security-winpc/hklm-registry-read-access-locked-for-one-user-only/c1555acd-5bcc-4952-9ad2-addfcd212eb5?tm=1507018410180 - posted also on Microsoft Forums, thanks for the advice